# VideoView restarts playback on lock screen

Tags: android, android-videoview, restart, lockscreen

I have an activity containing a vitamio VideoView, it works pretty well except for a annoying issue that causes the player to restart playback when I lock the screen.

As far as I can see it actually kills the activity upon locking and then restarts it.
Anyone have an idea on how I can fix this issue?

Thanks in advance,
X

Comment: Same problem here did you solve it?

Comment: @D4rWiNS Added an answer. There's probably a better way to do it, but that's what I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing was adding `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`
to my manifest. And I added `videoView.pause();` to my onPause() function in the VideoView activity to make sure it didn't continue playing.

Even though this worked I believe you must force the orientation for the VideoView activity, unless you want it to look weird when the orientation changes.